# Score not showing on screen but only in the console log

Tags: javascript, html, function, tags

Html code part works well

```
   <div class =”flex-blackjack-row-3
       <table>
           <tr>
              <th>Wins</th>
              <th>Losses</th>
               <th> Draws</th>
           </tr>

           <tr>
               <td><span id=”wins”>0</span></td>
               <td><span id=”losses>0</span></td>
               <td><span id=”draws>0<</span></td>
           </tr>
    </div>
```

In the Javascript code, everything else but the `showScore` works. `showScore` is not putting the score there.

```
function blackjackHit() {
   let card = randomCard();
   console.log(card);
   showCard(card, YOU);
   updateScore(card, YOU);
   showScore(card, YOU);
  }

function showScore(activePlayer) {
   Document.querySelector(activePlayer[‘scoreSpan’]).textContent = activePlayer[‘score’];
```

Comment: You have curly quotes around your attributes, they need to be straight quotes. You're also missing the closing quote after `class ="flex-blackjack-row-3`

Comment: also `Document` should be `document`

Comment: Are these copying errors, or do you have these problems in the real code? Make sure you turn off "smart quotes" when writing code.

Comment: What is the value of `activePlayer.scoreSpan`?

Answer (score 0):

You missed some brackets and used erroneous quotation marks in your code. So, you need to be careful with the syntax in HTML and Javascript, as usually, the browser digests everything you code without advice. However, you can use the developer's tools in your browser to detect some of those problems. Concerning your question, try with the code below, where those problems are corrected:

HTML

```
<div class ="flex-blackjack-row-3">
       <table>
           <tr>
              <th>Wins</th>
              <th>Losses</th>
               <th> Draws</th>
           </tr>

           <tr>
               <td><span id="wins">0</span></td>
               <td><span id="losses">0</span></td>
               <td><span id="draws">0</span></td>
           </tr>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
function blackjackHit() {
   let card = randomCard();
   console.log(card);
   showCard(card, YOU);
   updateScore(card, YOU);
   showScore(card, YOU);
  }

function showScore(activePlayer) {
   document.querySelector(activePlayer['scoreSpan']).textContent = activePlayer['score'];
}
```